# Is there a way to get Open Graph to NOT show a particular image?

Tags: image, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have recently started to use advertising on my blog, and since then every time someone presses the embedded 'like' button on a page the thumbnail that is shared on Facebook is a 'your ad here' button which is 11px wide by 6px high - not ideal.

I know the URL of this image, so is there any way of assigning it as a meta property NOT to be shared?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Dora

Comment: Nope. Provide what you want to have shared explicitly with OG meta tags.